# Multiple camera shots in vb

Tags: vb.net

See I have this simple vb.net codes that counts from 5 to 1 then says capture! I need to do this 4 consecutive times after the start button is clicked .. I tried a do until loop but it didn't work, I'm a newbie here so please help..

```
Public Class Form_welcome
    Dim Count As Integer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Count -= 1
        Label2.Text = Count
        If (Count = 0) Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Label2.Hide()
            Label3.Show()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Count = 5
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Label2.Text = Count
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: what is the problem with the above code?, it looks close to a good solution.

Comment: This runs 5..4..3..2..1 in the form then captures.. I wan it to continuously capture 4 pictures in one click so the user don't have to click the button again.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
Public Class Form_welcome

    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim pictureCount as integer = 4

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Count -= 1
        Label2.Text = Count
        If (Count = 0) Then
            pictureCount -=1
            If pictureCount = 0 then
                Timer1.Enabled = False
           End If
                'take a picture
            Label2.Hide()
            Label3.Show()
            Count = 5
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Count = 5
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Label2.Text = Count
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Pat I've tried your codes it's still the same.. I wanted to make multiple shots here. Thank you

Comment: This goes 5,4,3,2,1 takes a picture then repeats 5 times, thats not what you wanted?

Comment: yes .. actually i already kinda "solved?" it.. but the numbeing is wrong.. I want it to be 3.2.1 captured! My codes goes this wayy..

Answer (score 0):

Public Class Form_welcome
    Dim Count As Integer

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Admin_Login.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub Form_welcome_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Application.Exit()

End Sub

Private Sub Form_welcome_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Button4.Hide()
    Button5.Hide()
    Button6.Hide()


    'Timer1.Enabled = True
    'Label2.Text = Count
    'Timer1.Interval = 1000

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Count -= 1
    'Label2.Text = Count
    If (Count = -1) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Label3.Show()
        Label3.Hide()
        Label2.Hide()
        Button4.Show()
        Button5.Show()
        Button6.Show()
        PictureBox4.Hide()
        PictureBox3.Show()
        pict1.Show()
        pict2.Show()
        pict3.Show()
        pict4.Show()
        Button2.Hide()
    End If
    If (Count Mod 3) = 0 Then
        Label2.Text = "Captured!"
    Else
        Label2.Text = Count

    End If


End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Count = 12
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Label2.Text = Count
    Label2.Show()
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Application.Exit()

End Sub


Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Button2.Show()
    Button4.Hide()
    Button5.Hide()
    Button6.Hide()
    PictureBox3.Hide()
    pict1.Hide()
    pict2.Hide()
    pict3.Hide()
    pict4.Hide()
    PictureBox4.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: this is my new codes I kinda solved my first problem.. but the numbering is wrong. i wanted it to be 3.2.1 capture! 3.2.1 capture!